# I can not get the default validation message

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have a controller

```
@PutMapping(value = "/changeEmail", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public HttpEntity<ChangeEmailDTO> showChangeEMail(
        @RequestBody @Valid ChangeEmailDTO changeEmailDTO
) {
    System.out.println("Email: " + changeEmailDTO.getEmail());

    return ResponseEntity.ok(changeEmailDTO);
}
```

If the user has given bad data then throws a MethodArgumentNotValidException exception.
I created an exception handler

```
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ResponseBody
public ValidationErrorDTO processValidationError(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
    BindingResult result = ex.getBindingResult();
    List<FieldError> fieldErrors = result.getFieldErrors();

    return processFieldErrors(fieldErrors);
}

private ValidationErrorDTO processFieldErrors(List<FieldError> fieldErrors) {
    ValidationErrorDTO dto = new ValidationErrorDTO();

    for (FieldError fieldError: fieldErrors) {
        String localizedErrorMessage = resolveLocalizedErrorMessage(fieldError);
        dto.addFieldError(fieldError.getField(), localizedErrorMessage);
    }

    return dto;
}

private String resolveLocalizedErrorMessage(FieldError fieldError) {
    Locale currentLocale =  LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
    String localizedErrorMessage = messageSource.getMessage(fieldError, currentLocale);

    //If the message was not found, return the most accurate field error code instead.
    //You can remove this check if you prefer to get the default error message.
    if (localizedErrorMessage.equals(fieldError.getDefaultMessage())) {
        String[] fieldErrorCodes = fieldError.getCodes();
        localizedErrorMessage = fieldErrorCodes[0];
    }

    return localizedErrorMessage;
}
```

One of the fields has validation created by me

```
    @Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = EmailValidator.class)
@Target( {ElementType.FIELD} )
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface IsValidEmail {

    String message() default "Please enter a valid e-mail address.";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

And replace the default message in the properties file

```
IsValidEmail.changeEmailDTO.email=Please enter a valid e-mail address.
```

However, in the json data in the response is

```
{"fieldErrors"[{"field":"email","message":"IsValidEmail.changeEmailDTO.email"}]}
```

Why?

Comment: Could you share the code for `ValidationErrorDTO` and how is configured the @Bean `Validation` about infrastructure? Same request for `MessageSource` seems something is missing about infrastructure.

Comment: ValidationErrorDTO : https://pastebin.com/L1MP00Wm    EmailValidator: https://pastebin.com/H1LYN3pm

Comment: Do you have a bean that works around `LocalValidatorFactoryBean`?

Comment: I do not have. What is this? There is a difference whether I use Spring or Spring Boot. Because I use Spring Boot.

Comment: I have that `@Bean` declared because I work with `Spring Framework`. Clarify in your post you are working with `Spring Boot`.